# Metric for weak convergence on space of non-negative measures

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a Polish space, let $\mathcal{M}_+(X)$ be the space of non-negative measures on $X$. What is the metric that metrizes topology of *weak convergence* (i.e. where test functions are bounded continuous functions)? Does the *L'evy-Prohorov* metric work? Or the *Kantorovich-Rubinstein* one?
I keep finding references only for spaces of probability measures and not non-negative measures in general. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say the weak topology, do you mean the topology of weak convergence? i.e. where the test functions are bounded continuous functions?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification. I'll edit the text to make it clearer!

Comment: The Kantorovic-Rubinstein distance definitely works (see Chapter 8, Section 8.3 of Bogachev's "Measure Theory" and more specifically Theorem 8.3.2). Not sure about the Lévy-Prokhorov distance though